# Navigation menu close event

Tags: java, android, user-interface

There is an event that is triggered when the navigation menu is displayed:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {

// Handle the event


return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

And how to handle the event when it is closed?

My goal is to have the StatusBar color change when the side menu is opened, and when it is closed the color goes back.
I implemented the StatusBar color change in onSupportNavigateUp(). Now I need to make the color return when I close the side menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onSupportNavigateUp() is used when a "navigate to the before page" is called from someone....and not when the Side Menu is opened or closed.

If you're using DrawerLayout for the side menu, you can add a listener for Open/Close actions:

- DrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() { ... })